# Java proxy settings

Tags: java, networking, proxy, network-programming

I have global proxy settings made from Java control applet. It takes proxy settings from browser. I need to run a Java application that does not use global proxy settings, it has to use direct connection.

How can I do it with command line arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have a look here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html ?

You can set the system properties from the command line: `java ... -Dhttp.proxyHost=your-proxy.example.com ...`

Comment: I have proxy already set. What I want is to remove proxy settings and get direct connection.

Comment: I know this question is old... but nobody mentioned an easy way to bypass proxy in your applet CODE... There's no need to start it with any special arguments - if your applet is not going to use proxy, then it should call appropriate constructors (like `Socket(Proxy)` or `URLConnection(Proxy)`) with the argument `Proxy.NO_PROXY`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html#NO_PROXY

Answer (score -1):

open java control panel using

## javaws -viewer

General-> Network Settings -> direct Connetcion
now direct connection is set